# Getting all combinations inside an array, where the sum of all entries is equal to a given integer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to get all possible combinations inside an array with a given fixed size where the sum of all entries is equal to a given integer.
Example:

given integer n: 5 and given array size = 4

{0,0,0,5}
{0,0,5,0}
...
{0,0,1,4}
...
{1,1,1,2}
...

my goal is to get those combinations and save them inside a C++ vector.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: what help do you need? Did you try anything? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: How many different arrays do you expect? is there a clear way of writing them all down without getting duplicates or forgetting some? As soon as you've answered my last question, you've answered your question. It might or might not be the optimal algorithm, but it would work.

Comment: maybe this was ill asked, my question was if anyone knows an algorithm that does what i want.

Comment: if you dont have anything, my first advice is always to start with the naive brute force algorithm, it is easy to implement and either you can watch it collapse and know where it fails or you are lucky and it already does the job. There are n^2 possible combinations (each element is either in or out), write a loop and check if the sum is correct, thats basically all you need to get started

Comment: If negative numbers are allowed I suppose you'll have an infinite amount of combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple recursive approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> v;
vector<int> parts;

void partitions(int sum, int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        parts[k - 1] = sum;
        v.push_back(parts);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
        parts[k-1] = i;
        partitions(sum - i, k - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int k = 3;
    int sum = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        parts.push_back(0);
    partitions(sum, k);

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

5 0 0
4 1 0
3 2 0
2 3 0
1 4 0
0 5 0
4 0 1
3 1 1
2 2 1
1 3 1
0 4 1
3 0 2
2 1 2
1 2 2
0 3 2
2 0 3
1 1 3
0 2 3
1 0 4
0 1 4
0 0 5
```